# Construct a type list in compile-time, one at a time

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have a type list that I've been using but I want to make it cleaner.

My current implementation relies on all the types to be listed when declaring the type list.

```cpp
template<typename... Types>
struct TypeList {};

using MyCustomTypeList = TypeList<Type1, Type2, Type3>; // Currently listed in one place. This is what I want to avoid.
```

I would like to build a type list is such a way where I could just write: `ADD_TYPE(type)` and it would add to `MyCustomTypeList`.

One of the requirements is that a function call whose signature looks like

```cpp
template<typename... Types>
void MyFunction(TypeList<Types...>&&);
```

is still callable with `MyFunction( MyCustomTypeList{} );`

C++ 17 is available; boost or other libraries aren't.

Comment: C++ template metaprogramming language is a functional language; it doesn't have "variables" that can be modified. There's no magic that could make `MyCustomTypeList` name one type at one point of a program and a different type at another (if you think you've found a way, you are likely violating [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule) in there somewhere). You could write a meta-function that takes two type lists and combines them into a third, a la [`std::tuple_cat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update your list like so:

```
using list1 = pack<int>;
using list2 = push_back_t<list1, char>; // pack<int, char>
using list3 = push_back_t<list2, double>; // pack<int, char, double>
```

We can write `push_back` like this:

```
template <class T>
struct tag
{
    using type = T;
};

template <class T>
using detag = typename T::type;

////////////////////////////////

template <class, class>
struct push_back {};

template <template <class...> class C, class ... Ts, class NewT>
struct push_back <C<Ts...>, NewT> : tag<C<Ts..., NewT>> {};

template <class List, class NewT>
using push_back_t = detag<push_back<List, NewT>>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a9TjsM6on)

**Note:** I renamed `TypeList` to `pack`, as lowercase is standard for type traits.